# Re-write userprofile URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Any Ideas how to change remove .html in this mod-rewrite script Doesnt work if I remove ".html"

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L]
```

Works as

http://site.com/25.html
but wants to have it as

http://site.com/25